# Wait for renaming file, then open it in node

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, node.js-fs

I try to rename a file in node, then open it in a child process and rename it back when the child process closed by the user. But somehow I do not get the idea of promises into my head. The script works, but the function `ShowFile()` seems not wait for `writeFile()`. So when the external reader opens to fast the file is not ready. (when I use a slower program like Powerpoint to open the files everything works well)

What I have (in a very simplified way):

```
ShowFile(oldName, newname).then(function(result){
    child = result[0];
    tempfiles = result[1];
}).then(function(){
    child.on('close', function (code) {
        for (let x of tempfiles) {
            fs.rename(x.newname, x.oldname, (err) => {
                if(err) throw err;
            });
        }
    });
});

async function ShowFile(oldName, newname) {
    let tempfiles = await writeFiles(oldName, newname);
    let child = cp.exec(getCommandLine() + ' " ' + path to pdf reader + '"' + newname + '"');
    return [child, tempfiles];
}

async function writeFiles(oldName, newname) {
    return new Promise(function (fullfill, reject) {
        let tempfiles = [];// Array of filenames I get from another source
        for (let x of tempfiles) {
            fs.renameSync(oldName, newname);
            fs.writeFileSync(oldName, '', (err) => { //an empty file I need for something else 
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
        fullfill (tempfiles);
        reject ('error!');
    });
}
```

I'm aware that in this example the loop over tempfiles makes no sense, but it's really a very simplified example.

Comment: Why do you use a promise in `writeFiles`? I see only synchronous functions. `writeFiles` is a blocking function. It's not necessary to `await` it (after you remove the promise). `cp.exec` is an non-blocking, asynchronous call. You should await it or use `cp.execSync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function calls in `writeFiles` are blocking and synchronous. You don't need a promise. `cp.exec` is non-blocking and asynchronous. You have to await it or use the synchronous variant. `writeFileSync` doesn't expect a callback.

```
const tempfiles = ShowFile(oldName, newname);

for (let x of tempfiles) {
    fs.rename(x.newname, x.oldname, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
}

function ShowFile(oldName, newname) {
    let tempfiles = writeFiles(oldName, newname);
    cp.execSync(getCommandLine() + ' " ' + path to pdf reader + '"' + newname + '"');
    return tempfiles;
}

function writeFiles(oldName, newname) {
    let tempfiles = [];// Array of filenames I get from another source
    for (let x of tempfiles) {
        fs.renameSync(oldName, newname);
        fs.writeFileSync(oldName, ''); //an empty file I need for something else
    }
    return tempfiles;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. I started without a promise, but that also did not work. execSync is asynchronous, but that should not make any difference, does it?

Comment: @Torf `execSync` is blocking. _"The `child_process.execSync()` method is generally identical to `child_process.exec()` with the exception that the method will not return until the child process has fully closed."_ https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options

Comment: Nope. execSync does not work. I tried it the way you suggested, but the effect is the same. The external program is launched before the file is written, and furthermore if I use `execSync` the variable `child` is not a child process but an Uint8Array, which leads to `child.on` failing.

Comment: My error. You were absolutely right.  It is synced. there was a mistake in my exec path. Using execSync does not work, but that's tottally ok, as exec does.

Comment: @Torf I removed the returned value. You don't need `child.on('close'` with `execSync`. It's blocked until the process is closed